# Python OpenStack SDK list usage for all projects

Tags: openstack, openstacksdk

I'm looking for the python OpenStack SDK version of 'openstack usage list --start <start_time> '--end <end_time> -f ' which return each projects usage for a given period of time.
I've found conn.get_compute_usage(), which returns for a user?

Comment: Its not all available in the openstack sdk. There is some additional logic in the openstackclient. Maybe you can copy some things you need for your task. See https://github.com/openstack/python-openstackclient/blob/master/openstackclient/compute/v2/usage.py#L78

Comment: @Tobias Thank you! I'll build my own call then!

Answer (score 0):

You have `get_compute_usage(projectName)` which will give a detailed info for a project. It admits arguments for `start` and `end` time.

```
import openstack
from pprint import pprint
from datetime import datetime

os_connect = openstack.connect(
        auth_url=AUTH_URL,
        project_name=PROJECT_NAME,
        username=USERNAME,
        password=PASSWORD,
        region_name=REGION_NAME,
        user_domain_name=USER_DOMAIN_NAME,
        project_domain_name=PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID,
        app_version='1.0')

for p in os_connect.list_projects() :
   usage=os_connect.get_compute_usage(p['name'], start=datetime.strptime("2021-06-01","%Y-%m-%d"), end=datetime.strptime("2021-07-01","%Y-%m-%d"))
   #pprint(usage) #Probably too detailed
   print("Project:", p['name'])
   print("vcpus_usage", usage["total_vcpus_usage"])
   print("total_hours", usage["total_hours"])
```